# Converting ddmmyy-xxxx to date in R

Tags: r

I have a dateframe with a column with numbers that represent a date. So 110190-1111 is ddmmyy-xxxx, where the x's don't matter. It is implicit that the century is 1900.

```
df <- c("110190-1111", "220391-1111", "241287-1111")
```

I would like to have it converted to.

```
c("1990-01-11", "1991-03-22", "1987-12-24)
```

I have removed the last 4 digits and the "-" with the following.

```
ID <- c("110190-1111", "220391-1111", "241287-1111")
df <- data.frame(ID)
df <- df %>% mutate(date=gsub("-.*", "", ID))
```

I have tried fiddling with the as.Date function with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as.Date ignores junk at the end so

```
df %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(ID, "%d%m%y"))
```

giving:

```
           ID       Date
1 110190-1111 1990-01-11
2 220391-1111 1991-03-22
3 241287-1111 1987-12-24
```

or using only base R:

```
transform(df, Date = as.Date(ID, "%d%m%y"))
```

Comment: Oh, that's smart. Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <- dmy(df$date)
```